# Oxidation of Aromatic Methyl to Aldehyde by CAN

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

I read in my text that Ceric Ammonium Nitrate is used for oxidation of primary alcohols. But the surprising part was that, according to the book, it could oxidise aromatic methyl group to a -CHO group.
Is this actually true?
[image]

Comment: This review should tell you.  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/cr068408n?src=recsys

Comment: I would imagine that it proceeds via a single electron transfer, and the first step would be to create the benzyl alcohol.